# Conditional copy of cell from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, search

I want to take a name from a sheet (let's say A2 in a sheet called 'Names') and search for that same name in another worksheet (say A2 in 'Jobs'). After that name is found in the other worksheet I want to copy the value from the cell right next to it (still in 'Jobs' but B2) and return it to a different cell (E2) in the first sheet ('Names'). I ultimately want to loop though all of the values in A1 of 'Names' and fill in the whole sheet.

I have gotten this far:

```
Sub fixThis()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, col1 As Long, col2 As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim sheetOne As String
    Dim sheetTwo As String

    col1 = 5
    col2 = 1
    sheetOne = "Names"
    sheetTwo = "Job"
    lastrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2

           If sheetOne.Cells(i, col1).Value = sheetTwo.Cells(j, col2).Value Then

                sheetOne.Cells(i, 6).Value = sheetTwo.Cells(j, 2).Value

           End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You've cast `sheetOne` and `sheetTwo` as `String` objects, but you'd be better casting them as `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay if you store the sheet names as strings. but when you use them you need to use them to reference the sheet object like this: `Sheets("Sheetname").Cells().Value`
Or you can use a variable like this:

```
Dim strSheet1name as String
strSheet1name = "Sheet1"

Sheets(strSheet1name).Cells().Value
```

Finally if you really want to you can declare your own sheet object like

```
Dim ws as worksheets
ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Cells.value
```

To keep all of your above code the same you need to try replacing

```
       If sheetOne.Cells(i, col1).Value = sheetTwo.Cells(j, col2).Value Then

            sheetOne.Cells(i, 6).Value = sheetTwo.Cells(j, 2).Value

       End If
```

With

```
       If Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, col1).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, col2).Value Then

            Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, 2).Value

       End If
```

Then finally, if you're working with multiple sheets, you need to ad dmore detail to these lines:

```
lastrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row
```

And change them to something like:

```
lastrow1 = Sheets(SheetOne).Cells(Sheets(SheetOne).Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets(SheetTwo).Cells(Sheets(SheetTwo).Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row
```

The final version would look something like this:

```
Sub fixThis()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, col1 As Long, col2 As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim sheetOne As String
    Dim sheetTwo As String

    col1 = 5
    col2 = 1
    sheetOne = "Names"
    sheetTwo = "Job"
    lastrow1 = Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(Sheets(sheetOne).Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(Sheets(sheetTwo).Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2
            If Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, col1).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, col2).Value Then
                Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, 2).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an "object variable or with variable not set" error and the debugger is pointing me to the 'sheetOne = "Names"'line. I did switch it to work sheet as @Widor suggested in his comment above. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Oh, my code was independent of @Widor's comment. i'll update my answer to explain.

Comment: OK! Thanks! You have been a big help. That was precisely what I had in mind!